# How to write join query in room database kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I created two tables personal and academic table, In that personal table name, email, phone and then academic table name, address , dob. I need to join these two table using join query. Can you help me to join these tables using join in roomDatabase kotlin

Below query i wrote for join but it showing error, How can i write correct query in koltin roomdatabase

```
@Query("SELECT Userclass.name, userClass.email, userClass.phone, userStudent.address, userStudent.dobFROM userClass INNERJOIN userStudent ON userStudent.id = userClass.id WHERE userStudent.id = userClass.id")
    fun joinUser(personId: Int): List<UserClassStudent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Query("the_sql_with_the_join_or_joins")
fun the_function(): List<a_suitable_object_for_collecting_the_results>
```

Noting that the object(s) returned should contain variables that correlate/match the returned output column names (you can name the output columns us `AS`).

You should also be aware the such a query will return the cartesian product of the query unlike when using `@Relation` annotation where rather than incorporating a join room builds the list of child objects by querying the children extract all children irrespective of a join filtering the children.

Comment: @Query("SELECT Userclass.name, userClass.email, userClass.phone, userStudent.address, userStudent.dobFROM userClass INNERJOIN userStudent ON userStudent.id = userClass.id WHERE userStudent.id = userClass.id")
    fun joinUser(personId: Int): List<UserClassStudent> i wrote query like this but it showing error

Comment: @pavithas `INNERJOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` will result in an error, perhaps refer to https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html, keywords have to be separated.